# How to get TSpeedButton's Double Click event.?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

TspeedButton's Double click event has not fired when i double click on it.I need the different functionality for OnClick Event and OnDblClick Event.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that Delphi's double-click event is not used unless the GroupIndex property is non-zero - per the code below, this means that FDown can be true. If GroupIndex = 0 then FDown won't be true. The source for that event looks like this:

```
procedure TSpeedButton.WMLButtonDblClk(var Message: TWMLButtonDblClk);
begin
  inherited;
  if FDown then DblClick;
end;
```

If you wanted to play around you could remove the "if FDown" from this, recompile the vcl and it would probably work ok for you.

-Don

Comment: Instead of recompiling the VCL, I would commonly copy the code of TSpeedButton into my own unit, and rename it, and replace the TSpeedButton in my app with a TXYZSpeedButton, where XYZ is the corporate component prefix. I would not redistribute such source, and so such techniques are not usable in an open source application, but in closed source commercial applications, it's okay.  I wanted a TSpeedButton with better hot-image support (mouse over and the image changes) and doing this was impossible without essentially cloning and modifying the TSpeedButton sources out of buttons.pas.